# How to validate my form if next button clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm coding a step-by-step form . that include a jquery script that divide my forms. So in the first form i have to put just one button and that is the next button to bring the client on the next form

But i have to deal with that if i click over the next button on my first form it gose to the other form without validiating the section inside the first form.

Here the buttons code

```
<input  name="Next"  type="submit" id='button1' value="Next" />
```

Here the jquery script that i think has to do with the next tag besides im not good at jquery .:

```
$(".next").click(function(){

    if(animating) return false;
animating = true;

current_fs = $(this).parent();
next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

//activate next step on progressbar using the index of next_fs
$("#progressbar li").eq($("fieldset").index(next_fs)).addClass("active");

//show the next fieldset
next_fs.show(); 
//hide the current fieldset with style
current_fs.animate({opacity: 0}, {
    step: function(now, mx) {
        //as the opacity of current_fs reduces to 0 - stored in "now"
        //1. scale current_fs down to 80%
        scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
        //2. bring next_fs from the right(50%)
        left = (now * 50)+"%";
        //3. increase opacity of next_fs to 1 as it moves in
        opacity = 1 - now;
        current_fs.css({'transform': 'scale('+scale+')'});
        next_fs.css({'left': left, 'opacity': opacity});
    }, 
    duration: 800, 
    complete: function(){
        current_fs.hide();
        animating = false;
    }, 
    //this comes from the custom easing plugin
    easing: 'easeInOutBack'
});
```

The question is how to go to the other form but with valididating the first one .
thanks in advance

Comment: Please stop posting duplicate questions.

Answer (score 1):

Form validation can be done like this form name="myForm" **action="demo_form.asp"** **onsubmit="return validateForm()"** method="post"

The validateform() function only returns false: If the input is not false the action in this case will be going to demo_form.asp, in your case will be going to the next step...

For a good example goto: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

Comment: it is more complicated because it has a form of validation already so if i put anohter on the script that divide my form than it shows 2 but i want the the validition that is included or the screipt that is included in my eg index.html code to be active a bit confused i now besides thanks for your ansewer